# Error from server (Forbidden): namespaces is forbidden - AWS EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks

Already went so many tutorials but didn't get any help
Setup EKS Cluster, Installed `kubectl` on master & Getting Below error.

kubectl get namespace

`Error from server (Forbidden): namespaces is forbidden: User "system:node:ip-x-x-x-x.us-east-2.compute.internal" cannot list resource "namespaces" in API group "" at the cluster scope`

Tried, not worked - `kubectl config set-context —-user xx yourclustername`]

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think his error usually indicates that the user does not have permissions to view namespaces in your EKS cluster. You need to update the IAM policy associated with the node instance profile or configure RBAC roles and bindings for users/groups within your EKS cluster so they can access resources like namespaces.

I believe you need to configure the IAM policy associated with the node instance profile. You can do something like (just my example):

1. Log into your AWS console and select “IAM” from the services menu
2. Select “Policies” from left-hand navigation pane
3. Search for “AmazonEKSWorkerNodePolicy" in filter box
4. Click on AmazonEKSWorkerNodePolicy  and then click "Edit Policy" button at top right corner of page
5. Expand "Resources -> Actions" section of page
6. Select checkbox next to list item called "ListNamespaces", save policy changes by clicking review change button at bottom right corner
7. You should see a success message confirming that your new policies have been saved successfully
8. Restart EKS nodes after updating IAM polices
9. Try running kubectl command again

See if that works.

Comment: Hey Kenneth, Here its

`{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:DescribeInstances",
                "ec2:DescribeInstanceTypes",
                "ec2:DescribeRouteTables",
                "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
                "ec2:DescribeSubnets",
                "ec2:DescribeVolumes",
                "ec2:DescribeVolumesModifications",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcs",
                "eks:DescribeCluster"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}`